# Extract count of each status by month

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following database:

```
Reservations
| id | status    | created_at          |
|  1 | Canceled  | 2019-12-16 11:46:11 |
|  2 | Fulfilled | 2019-11-15 23:03:24 |
|  3 | Accepted  | 2019-12-13 12:04:13 |
```

So I want to extract a collection by months in which there's the count of each status.
I.e.:

```
['Month', 'Accepted', 'Fulfilled', 'Canceled'],
['Jul 2019', 4, 5, 9],
['Aug 2019', 5, 6, 7]
```

I have several ways of approaching that but all require additional work outside eloquent and don't look very elegant.

Comment: use the `groupBy(\DB::raw('month(created_at))` and set the custom select

Comment: I am grouping them exactly like that, but I can't achieve the result I've quoted in the question, could you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the Collection::countBy() method. (https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-countBy)

```
Reservation::countBy('status');
```

You can always constrain your query before calling the `countBy()` function

Comment: I don't have the countBy, probably older version of Laravel.